# LIGO may have inadvertently detected the helioseismic burst from the Sun on 14 September 2015

Tags: gravitational-waves, ligo

Here is a quote from an online article:
"A gust is on the way. NOAA forecasters expect a stream of high-speed solar wind to reach Earth on Sept. 14th-15th, sparking renewed displays of high-latitude auroras."
Ref: http://www.spaceweather.com/archive.php?view=1&day=14&month=09&year=2015

Did the LIGO group actually detect a gravitational wave from the merger of two black holes, or did they detect the Sun-Earth weak coupling of the helioseismic burst generated by the solar flare eruption on September 14, 2015? It is clear from the LIGO data that the phenomenon was detected by Livingston, LA first at 09:50:45 UTC before it arrived at Hanford, WA, which is consistent with an EM pulse vectoring from the Sun in the east.

Also the waveform of the detected signal is indicative of dispersion consistent with what would be expected from a helioseismic burst.
“A unique characteristic of solar seismic waves is acceleration. The solar waves accelerated from an initial speed of 22,000 miles per hour (9.8 km/sec) to a maximum of 250,000 miles per hour (112 km/sec) before disappearing. In contrast, water ripples on Earth travel outward at a constant velocity.”
Ref: http://www.vibrationdata.com/Newsletters/August2001_NL.pdf

I just wonder.

Comment: Why would a solar phenomenon mimic the signal from a black hole merger? Do you have a model for the probability of that?

Comment: Yes, a solar phenomenon is perfectly able to mimic a so-called "gravity wave" from the presumed merger of two black holes ... take a look at this: http://www.earth-planets-space.com/content/67/1/168/figure/F5

Comment: Not even the time scale is correct... and I really can't see anything that would even remotely resemble "perfectly".

Comment: If you wait long enough (say 14 years as in the case of LIGO) and you put a lot of resources into searching for a signal that matches your model of a gravity wave, then you will be perfectly able to find a signal that matches your model from a solar phenomenon nearby, and it would have nothing to do with the merger of two black holes . By the way, a type III radio burst from a solar flare is also able to mimic the characteristics of a so-called gravity wave a billion light-years away.

Comment: LIGO didn't wait 14 years, they didn't have enough sensitivity to measure at this level. Even so the time scale of what you are showing and the signal the LIGO has received are not the same. Even if they were the same none of the signals that you are showing match. Since it's your hypothesis that what they have seen is an unrelated phenomenon, it's your responsibility to show evidence, which you have not. For me that pretty much sends your case back to your drawing board.

Comment: If one ventures to be fully forthcoming and perfectly explicit, one would say that it must be a case of the most fortuitous case of good luck known to science that the LIGO team was able to detect the merger of two black holes a billion light years away, and do so **a mere two days after upgrading the sensitivity of the LIGO systems.** Doesn't it make you wonder?

Comment: Either that... or one would actually read the documentation of how it was done and why it was expected to work. In any case, you still don't have anything but hot air... if you can upgrade it to some giant foam hands flapping in the wind, then I will be interested.

Comment: There is enough bandwidth in the solar phenomena that I showed above to obtain a match that agrees with the model of the black-hole mergers; you have to do a cross-correlation search (i.e. matched filtering), after the prerequisite bandpass filtering and noise-suppression. If you have the raw data, then you can find a signal that matches your model, within the limits of background noise and amplitude uncertainty. You can find almost anything this way, but you must verify your finding by independent means. Just claiming that you have found a "signal" that matches your model is not good science.

Comment: Seriously, if you can get some foam hands to go with this, I will listen, but that's not even foam hands, yet.

Comment: Also worth noting that the Sun is far from the direction deduced for GW150914.

Comment: Besides all the other more relevant points about frequencies and direction, LIGO also has many, many instruments measuring other things directly — including cosmic rays and radio waves, not to mention winds, seismic activity, sound, etc.  They *directly* measure these with instruments that are far more sensitive to those specific noise sources than LIGO itself, so that if any such noise occurred at the time of a claimed "detection", that "detection" will be flagged as potential contamination, rather than a real gravitational wave signal.

Answer (score 8):

There is always some chance that the signal that has been measured could be caused by something other than a pair of coalescing black holes.

The refereed paper assesses the probability that the signal might have arisen as a consequence of some sort of noise in the detectors. The estimates are imprecise but range from about 1 false detection every 10,000 years for a signal with this power (seen in both detectors) to 1 every 200,000 years for a signal conforming to the characteristics of a merging black hole system.

Of course, these statistics do not preclude some other completely unknown and unpredicted astrophysical phenomenon causing the lengths of the detector arms to oscillate in a similar way.

If you have a theory, then now is the time to publish it, because once there is a population of such events (I note the paper says that another source was detected with a false alarm probability of one in two years and also looked like a black hole merger), then their spatial distribution will also become apparent. If they are indeed dominated by distant massive black hole mergers then one expects the distribution to be isotropic, modulo the directional sensitivity of the detectors.